# Show an Image in a PictureBox using the URL from an Access database

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I have an Access database containing cards for a card game, with their picture. One of the columns in my database contains the url of these cards' images.
However, I'm struggling to show the image from the URL in a PictureBox.

I tried to download it using the HttpClient class, but I was getting too many errors so here is the code that doesn't have any errors but still doesn't work:

```
' adds an image to a PictureBox
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(dataSet.Tables("YGO cards").Rows(0).Item(8))
```

This generates an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Do you know a way to display the images using the URL?
There are thousands of cards with different URLs.

Here is two examples of them:
https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/27551.jpg
https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/41777.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfiletaskasync) method to download the Bitmap files (if you need to store tham and, eventually, only download updates of the Bitmaps) then load the Image from a file:
(to use this asynchronous method, your code needs to be contained in a `async` method/event handler)

```
Dim imageURL As String = "https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/27551.jpg"
Dim imageURI As Uri = New Uri(imageURL)
Dim bitmapFile As String = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, $"images\{imageURI.Segments.Last()}")

Using client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(imageURI, bitmapFile)
    PictureBox1.Image?.Dispose()
    PictureBox1.Load(bitmapFile)
End Using
```

My suggestion is to register the file name of the Bitmap in the Database; the file name only, not a complete path: the location of the Images should be determined when the application downloads the images the first time and might change (or the user might change it, for any reason). If you need to relocate the Images, you just need to update the storage path.
This information could also be stored in the Database.

Add a boolean Field, `[Downloaded]`, to set to `True` when the Image has been downloaded (to filter the records that don't have an associated bitmap yet).

---

If you don't want or can't download the Bitmaps, you can use the [PictureBox.LoadAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadasync) method (or the synchronous `PictureBox.Load` method) to let the control do the job for you:

```
Dim imageURL As String  = "https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/27551.jpg"
PictureBox1.Image?.Dispose()    
PictureBox1.LoadAsync(imageURL)
```

Or use the [WebClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloaddatataskasync) method to download the image data as a Byte array and generate a new Bitmap from a MemoryStream. The Bitmap won't be saved on disc:

```
Dim imageURL As String = "https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/27551.jpg"
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(
    Await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(New Uri(imageURL))
)

Using image As Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
    PictureBox1.Image?.Dispose()
    PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(image.Clone(), Image)
End Using

ms.Dispose()
client.Dispose()
```

Comment: Well, I'm glad it was helpful :)

Comment: Add a column in your database for downloaded so your program will know where to look for the picture (locale storage or web) The website only wants you to download an image once and then store it locally.